# Tooltip on my CSS navigation menu isn't working

Tags: html, css, pagination, navigation

I'm in the beginning stages of putting together a web page and I want to create a dot navigation menu like this one: http://globalthinkers.foreignpolicy.com/#main

I'm pretty sure I wrote the code correctly but the tooltip part of the navigation menu isn't working. I've pasted my code below. Any help would be appreciated!

```css
body {
  
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-size: 100%;

font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 100%;

}

#block1 {

    background-image: url("http://mchdata.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/hospital.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 200%;

}

#block2 {

    background-image: url("http://allenhardwick.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/inside_house.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 200%;
    color: white;
   

}

#block3 {
    background-color: #7CE87C;
     background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 200%;
    color: white;
}

#block4 {
    background-color: #7C8CE8;
     background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 200%;
    color: white;
}

#block5 {
    background-color: #E87C83;
     background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 200%;
    color: white;
}

  
@media screen and (min-width: 535px){#brand-tagline{font-size:20px;font-size:2rem}}

#dotsNav li{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    margin:30px 0;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    cursor:pointer;

}

#dotsNav {
    z-index: 9992;
}

#dotsNav.pagination{
    position: fixed;
}


#dotsNav ul {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        cursor: default;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }





#dotsNav li a {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        outline: none;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #9d9d9d;
        text-indent: -999em; /* make the text accessible to screen readers */
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
    }

#dotsNav li a:focus {
        outline: none;
    }


#dotsNav li a:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
#dotsNav li a {
    overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    }
    #dotsNav li a:hover{
        transform: scale(1.5);
    }

    #dotsNav li a::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease;
        transition: height 0.3s ease;
    }

    #dotsNav li a:hover::after {
        height: 100%;
    }

    #dotsNav li.active a::after {
        height: 100%;
    }
    #dotsNav li.active a{
      -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
      box-shadow:         0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    }

    #dotsNav .pp-tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        top: -2px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        max-width: 220px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

     #dotsNav .pp-tooltip.left {
        right: 20px;
    }
    #dotsNav .pp-tooltip.left a{
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        overflow: none;
    }

    #dotsNav .pp-tooltip{
        position:absolute;
        top: -2px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        max-width: 220px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    #dotsNav .pp-slidesNav span {
        top: 2px;
        left: 2px;
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }

   
#dotsNav.pagination{
    position:fixed;
}

 #dotsNav .pp-slidesNav span {
        top: 2px;
        left: 2px;
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }



    .pagination {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 41px;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -126px 0 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.pagination li { margin: 0 0 12px; }
.pagination a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #9d9d9d;
}

.pagionation .active a

#wrapper{
    margin-top: -92px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

<title>HEALTH CARE REFORM EXPLAINED</title>
</head>


<body>


<div id="wrapper">
 <ul class="pagination" id="dotsNav">

  <li data-menuanchor="block1">
   <a href="block1">Block 1</a>
  </li>

  <li data-menuanchor="block2">
   <a href="#block2">Block 2</a>
  </li>

  <li data-menuanchor="block3">
   <a href="#block3">Block 3</a>
  </li>

  <li data-menuanchor="block4">
   <a href="#block4">Block 4</a>
  </li>

  <li data-menuanchor="block5">
   <a href="#block5">Block 5</a>
  </li>

 </ul>

</div>


<div class="container">
 <div id="block1">
  <div style="color:white; margin:40px; padding:40px;">

  <h2>HEALTH CARE REFORM EXPLAINED</h2>

   

   </div>
  </div>
 <div id="block2"
 <div style="color:white; margin:40px; padding:40px;">

  <h2>London</h2>

   <p>
    London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
   </p>

  </div>
  </div>

 <div id="block3"
 <div style="background-color: black; color:white; margin:40px; padding:40px;">

  <h2>London</h2>

   <p>
   London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
   </p>
  </div> 
 </div>

 <div id="block4"
 <div style="color:black; margin:40px; padding:40px;">

  <h2>London</h2>

   <p>
    I been drankin, I been drankin.
   </p>

  </div>
  </div>

 <div id="block5"
 <div style="color:black; margin:40px; padding:40px;">

  <h2>London</h2>

   <p>
    London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
   </p>

  </div>
  </div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explain the results you are expecting.

Comment: The result she is expecting is clear, the white words beside the dots. What she needs to explain is: where are those words in the code ?

Answer (score 0):

ohh you missed **#**

Here your are :)

```html
<li data-menuanchor="block1">
<a href="#block1">Block 1</a>
</li>
```

Good LUCK!

Comment: He missed #, but this is *another* problem

Answer (score 0):

Update/replace your **wrapper** div with the code below.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul class="pagination" id="dotsNav">
        <li data-menuanchor="block1" title="block1 tooltip">
            <a href="block1">Block 1</a>
        </li>

        <li data-menuanchor="block2" title="block2 tooltip">
            <a href="#block2">Block 2</a>
        </li>

        <li data-menuanchor="block3" title="block3 tooltip">
            <a href="#block3">Block 3</a>
        </li>

        <li data-menuanchor="block4" title="block4 tooltip">
            <a href="#block4">Block 4</a>
        </li>

        <li data-menuanchor="block5" title="block5 tooltip">
            <a href="#block5">Block 5</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Change/update your tooltip text according to the requirements.

[image: Screenshot of updated/running code]

Comment: I replaced the wrapper div with the code you so generously provided, however I'm not sure what to do next to update/change my tooltip text in the CSS to reflect the change.

Comment: I think now doing hover on data-menuanchor a tooltip will be shown.
update/change according to your requirements.
<li data-menuanchor="block1" title="**block1 tooltip**">

Comment: I'm applying the CSS tooltip code to #dotsNav is that right? It's still not working

Comment: I have added screenshot with my answer of updated/running code, In which you can see while doing hover on data-menuanchor a tooltip is shown **block2 tooltip**.

Comment: @RebeccaHarris, I have taken your raw code, updated only the HTML part. There is NO change in the CSS part.

Comment: @RebeccaHarris, If you have replaced your wrapper div with the div I have provided, that means by now tooltip should be shown.
Just hover on any of the data-menuanchor a tooltip will be displayed.